# Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. - error when using my site in an iframe on IOS

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, iframe, mobile, certificate

my website is being used by a third party iframe, the page has a single form

the link for the iframe is as follows
https://MYWEBSITE.com:8443/en?token=eyJhbGciOiAiSFMyNTawfc%3D&token2=ABC

:8443 is there because I am using multiple sets of certificates, some only with port 8443, others only with port 443.

whenever using mobile IOS, the website first load fine within the iframe, but after I try to submit the form, I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “MYWEBSITE.com”, which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

I use aws with elastic beanstalk load balancer

Sorry my English, and thank you for your help :)

P.S. it works fine on chrome, only safari is the problem